# Rails convert datetime to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just need 1 instance where I have a date field instead of a datetime field. No need in creating a new column just for 1 date.

How do I convert datetime to date when displaying data?

**HTML that needs converting;**

```
<td> <%= product.pDate %> </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are actually a number of approaches you can take in Rails. [Link Nguyen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67171556/1326518) is the pure Ruby approach, which works here and would also work in other Ruby contexts outside of Rails.

Rails also adds [`#to_formatted_s` and `#to_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_s) (they're aliases of one another) to the date and time objects, e.g.:

```rb
<%= product.pDate.to_s(:long) %>
```

Rails define some date formats by default, and you can add your own by adding values to the `Date::DATE_FORMATS` array in an initializer (see [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_s) for examples).

A additional, slightly newer approach uses the locale files (e.g., `config/locales/en.yml`) to define formats, which can then be accessed in your views using the `l` (for **l**ocalize) helper:

```rb
# Your ERb file
<%= l product.pDate, format: :short %>

# Your configs/locale/xx.yml file
# NB: `short` is defined by default but you can redefine it if you want

en:
  date:
    formats:
      short: "%m/%d/%y"
```

See the [Rails i18n guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) for more.

The advantage of both Rails approaches is that you can decide on a standard style, or collection of standard styles, that you apply to dates/times everywhere in your app. If you were to decide to switch from two-digit years to four, or vice versa, the `strftime` approach would require editing every view (and not missing any), but with either `Date#to_s` or `l()` you change the configuration format in one place. The i18n approach allows you to further customise date formats for international markets if you want to (for example, day/month/year is an almost exclusively US ordering, so you might want to use a different format for other languages).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `strftime`. for example `product.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")`